# Find values by date and sum them

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have some data in the format:

```
 date_1  date_2  date_3  pay_1  pay_2  pay_3
2017-03 2017-04 2017-05  115.3  110.5  115.7
2018-03   NaT     NaT     98.2   nan    nan
2017-08 2017-09   NaT    200.0  200.0   nan 
   .       .       .        .      .      .
   .       .       .        .      .      .
```

Where the data columns were initialy in `datetime64` and I turned into strings, and the pay columns are in `int`. The indices are unique formatted numbers. I made sure they are unique.

So, what I need is to know how much was paid in every month since the start date of the base. Here's what I have tried:

```
group = pd.DataFrame(); group['dates']= sp.date_hw().astype(str); group['paid'] = 0
col_array = df_hw.columns

for i in range(len(group)):
    for j in range(len(ind_array)):
        for k in range(3):
            if '-'.join(df_hw.loc[ind_array[j]][col_array[k]].split('-')[:-1]) == group.loc[i]['dates']:
                group.loc[i]['paid'] = group.loc[i]['paid'] + df_hw.loc[ind_array[j]][col_array[k]+15]
```

Basically, the `group` dataframe is where my results should be stored, and the expected output is:

```
     dates     paid 
    2015-01  11452.43 
    2015-02   9326.32   
    2015-03  14398.95
       .        .      
       .        .
```

Finally, the problem is that it is taking A LOT of time to complete and not producing any results. There is no way that there isn't an easier, simpler way to do this, but I just could not figure it out myself.

Comment: I will edit the post with this information

Comment: It's not clear from your output what you need, since it's not at all related to your sample data. Do you need one row per day, where the value is the sum of any values for that day in your entire DataFrame?

Comment: Almost, I need that but for every month. I'm sorry my explanation wasn't clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reshape first with `pd.wide_to_long` then you can `groupby.sum` without issue.

```
res = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['date', 'pay'], 
                      sep='_', i='index', j='num')

res.groupby('date').sum()
```

#### Output

```
           pay
date          
2017-03  115.3
2017-04  110.5
2017-05  115.7
2017-08  200.0
2017-09  200.0
2018-03   98.2
NaT        0.0
```

---

Alternatively, keep the full `datetime64` (even with the days) and use a `PeriodIndex` to group up to the month after reshaping.

```
res = pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['date', 'pay'], 
                      sep='_', i='index', j='num')
res.groupby(pd.PeriodIndex(res.date, freq='M')).sum()

           pay
date          
2017-03  115.3
2017-04  110.5
2017-05  115.7
2017-08  200.0
2017-09  200.0
2018-03   98.2
```

Comment: Wow, it's so simple and elegant. Thank you!

Comment: Yup, this is exactly what `wide_to_long` is meant for :D

Comment: @ALollz, So nice! I tried to do something similar using `pd.melt()` but couldn't. Is it possible?

Comment: @politicalscientist It can be done with melt, but there is extra manipulation (with `.str.split` and `unstack` so that you can pair `date_1` with `pay_1`. `wide_to_long` truly shines when the suffixes, `'_1'`, link different stubs